# DjangoFilterBackend: Filtering on a primary key results in "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models (Product & Category) which every product has a linked category.

I have installed `DjangoFilterBackend` which the hope of filtering on the `category` field to return a list of products in that category.

However, whenever I send the query in Postman. I receive the error `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.`.

I have tried filtering on another field in my `product` model (`name` for an example) and that works fine. So i'm not sure if i'm missing something for `category` to work.

`Product/View.py`:

```
class ProductView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ('category', 'name')
```

`Products/Models.py`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True, blank=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=product_photo_path)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    trending = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

Products/serializers.py

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.CharField(source='category.name', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('category', 'name', 'photo', 'quantity', 'description', 'price', 'in_stock', 'trending')
```

The query I am using is a GET request to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products?category=xxxx - I am sending no payload. The response I am receiving is a `400 Bad Request` and the exact error is:

{
    "category": [
        "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."
    ]
}
```

Comment: It is weird!!! coz, `category` seems not a ***choice*** here.... Can you update your question with the requested URL (its already in OP), payload (if any), HTTP method and **the exact response** you have got

Answer (score 1):

Ah-ha!

I changed the model to:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True, blank=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=product_photo_path)
    **category = models.ForeignKey(Category, to_field='name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)**
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    trending = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure, but try to filter on field `category_id`, this field is created automatically for FK fields

Comment: hmm.. I just tried `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products?category=2` and it's returning results. How do I transform it into filtering  the 'name' in the model field and not the PK?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody will ever need the answer, to be able to use the name of a foreign field to filter instead of the primary key use a double underscore i.e `category__name` in this case. Note that name in this case is the field of the foreign model that you want to filter with and you can replace it with your field accordingly.